# How to convert dataframe to csv?

Tags: python, json, csv, dataframe

I have Json file and I converted it to dictionary then I extract from it some data which are the name of classes.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_json("/content/Test1.json")
with open('/content/Test1.json') as handle:
    dictdump = json.loads(handle.read())
for elem in dictdump : 
    print(elem['fullyQualifiedName'])
```

then it returns these which are the name of classes:

```
android.support.v4.app.Watson
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreatePanelMenuListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnMenuItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnPreparePanelListener
```

I want to insert this data into a CSV file .Each name of classes in a line any solution please

Comment: Use `df.to_csv()` . Take a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way you can achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

import json

classDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['NameOfClass', 'Type_of_smells'])

with open('/content/Test1.json') as handle:
    dictdump = json.loads(handle.read())

for elem in dictdump :     
    class_dict = {'NameOfClass': elem['fullyQualifiedName'], 'Type_of_smells': elem['WhatEverYourJsonNameIs']}
    class_name = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(class_dict, orient='index')
    class_name = class_name.transpose()
    classDF = pd.concat([classDF, class_name])

classDF.to_csv('/path/class_name.csv', mode='a', header=True)
```

Comment: Please if i want to add a line to my CSV how can I do this ?

Comment: @oumayma where do you want to add this line? in `NameOfClass` column?

Comment: I want to add line called Type_of_smells and the values of this line are extarcted from json file the same like 'Name of a classes' but a line and of course in the same CSV. finally I want a CSV with a line a column like a table and the column contain the name of classes and the line the type of smells beacuse then i Will calculate the number of type_OF_Smell on each class

Comment: @oumayma I edited my answer based on your needs. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank uuu very much very helpful !

Comment: @oumayma You're welcome. can I ask why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here and I don't know this procedure  I accepted your answer now and sorry again

Comment: @oumayma That's totally okay. I just wanted to know if there is any problem in my answer! I'm glad that my answer was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a json into df if your dataframe is something like this:

```
    fullyQualifiedName
0   android.support.v4.app.Watson
1   android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnCreateOptionsM...
2   android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnPrepareOptions...
3   android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnOptionsItemSel...
4   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock
5   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCrea...
6   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCrea...
7   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnMenu...
8   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnOpti...
9   com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnPrep...
```

Then you could use [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) and just do:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv",columns=["fullyQualifiedName"], index=False,header=False)
```

Result (contents of csv file):

```
android.support.v4.app.Watson
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener
android.support.v4.app.Watson.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreatePanelMenuListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnMenuItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnPreparePanelListener
```

Set

```
header=True
```

if you want column name also in csv as header.